# change logic stock status for visibility product view

Tags: magento-1.9, stock-status

i would like to change logic **visibility:status**
i want logic work like this

`if any simple(child)product has qty > 0` Show product status in stock else show out of stock.
**My code is**
**app/design/frontend/default/mythem/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml**

```
   <?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<div class="available_price">
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>   
    <?php if((int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty() > 0): ?>
            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

it logic working but issue is `if configurable product has qty > 0` show out of stock.

i want  this logic just work for simple(child products)

Answer (score 0):

You can put product type condition with your qty check condition like,

```
<?php if($_product->isSalable()) : ?>
```

This will display only simple products which has `qty>0` as in stock.

Comment: thansk bro Your condition is right but when find in configurable product  QTY is 0 it show **out of stock**

Comment: If configurable product QTY is 0, then you want to show **in stock** or **out of stock**?

Comment: I  want this condition  target only simple(child) products 
like this if any child product have qty > 0  that  show in-stock

Comment: and if no any  qty  in simple child products that should be show out of stock

Comment: now issue is some parents(configurable) products have qty > 0 and some  parents(configurable) products have qty == 0

Comment: Then you can directly use `isSalable()` function on your product. check updated answer.

Comment: this function  not working at my side

Comment: Try `$_product->isSaleable()`. If still getting error, please provide your error log.

Comment: There no any error log